# Fetch table by column name : PHP ,PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have the following table:

```
columns, id , name , value
```

I want to get from pdo result like the following:

```
array = ["name1", "name2" ,"name3"]
```

and each "name" array will hold the value

so to get the value of name 1 I will do something like:
`$array["name1"]["value"]`  and I will get the value by name and not by id

I tried to that with :

```
$sth = $this->db->prepare("SELECT name ,value FROM table");

$result = $sth->fetchAll(FETCH_ASSOC);
```

but it returned index array and only by id I can get the name and value

Comment: You need to process that array by yourself to get that format.

Comment: You need to format array at your end to get the desired format

Comment: You have 2 choices, or you format the array after fetching.Or you use an embedded select statement to get the same table by name.

Answer (score 2):

To do this, you need to get an associative array of this type:

```
$list= array(
'name1'=>'value1',
'name2'=>'value2',
'name3'=>'value3'
)
```

and not the simple type you mentioned:

```
array = ["name1", "name2" ,"name3"]
```

So you follow this procedure:

```
 $res = $this->db->prepare("SELECT name,value FROM table");
    $res->execute($params);
    $fetch= $res->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    $list = array();
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($fetch); $i++) {
        $list[$fetch[$i]['name']] = $fetch[$i]['value'];
    }

    $res->closeCursor();
```

Answer (score 0):

You must make new array with converted data:

```
$sth = $this->db->prepare("SELECT name, value FROM table");
$result = array_values($sth->fetchAll(FETCH_ASSOC));
$new = [];
foreach($result as $ar) {
    $new[$ar['name']] = $ar['value'];
}
```